# When str vs repr is used and called

Tags: python, string

I've written the following two methods in a class:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return 'REPR: %s' % self.__class__.__name__

def __str__(self):
    return 'STR: %s' % self.__class__.__name__
```

And to see when they are called:

```
>>> print t
STR: TPR
>>> t
REPR: TPR
>>> str(t) #obvious
'STR: TPR'
>>> repr(t) #obvious
'REPR: TPR'
```

Is there a general rule of thumb as to which one is called when, for example, when printing a `%s` or within a format string, etc. Or is it safe to assume that `str` is always called if the obj is ever called in some sort of formatted string/unicode place?

Finally, if I ever wanted to "just use one", what would be a better way to do this?

```
def __repr__(self):
    return __str__(self)
```

or:

```
def __str__(self):
    return __repr__(self)
```

Or does it not matter?

Comment: This seems like a reasonable explanation? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/str-vs-repr-in-python/#targetText=str()%20is%20used%20for,us%20while%20str%20may%20not. Specifically "The print statement and str() built-in function uses `__str__` to display the string representation of the object while the repr() built-in function uses `__repr__` to display the object."

Comment: @mayosten, just note that `print('%r'%obj) ` also uses repr

Comment: @Demi-Lune I actually think this gets a bit more complicated than what's listed as a duplicate. For example, doing something like `str([date, date, date])` will use `repr` and not string on all the list elements.

Comment: There's indeed a remark on this point in the 1st answer of the duplicate. I find their point on "str for human readable " and "repr for unambiguous and `eval`uable"  is the key point ... though in the end the developer always gets last decision (for instance, `np.zeros(100)` has an exact repr, but `repr(np.zeros(10000))` shows `array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.])` )